# design in flutter for cards

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how do I make a card list view like the below picture?

[image]

Comment: These are called `chip`s, not cards. Check out this https://medium.com/flutterdevs/chip-widgets-in-flutter-7a2d3d34597c

Comment: This package might help - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You Can Use `Chips` and `Wrap` both widget, to achieve above result*

First Make a list of your `Strings` or You Can also use any dynamic data list.

```
List<String> itemList = ['Guitar', 'Music', 'Fishing'];
```

Now Add This line of `code` to show your `Chips` wraped in a Wrap `widget`

```
          Wrap(
              spacing: 8.0,
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                  itemList.length, // place the length of the array here
                  (int i) {
                return Chip(
                  onDeleted: () {
                    
                  },
                  deleteIconColor: Colors.white,
                  label: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    child: Text("${itemList[i]}",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xffffffff),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                            fontSize: 12.0),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Chip widget. It's simple to use.
here is an example:

```
Wrap(
  children: [
    Chip(
      label: Text('Dancing'),
    ),
    Chip(
      label: Text('Outdoors'),
    ),
    Chip(
      label: Text('Writer'),
    ),
  ]
)
```